# How can I upload a fresh photo to Facebook on Android?

Tags: facebook, photos

How can I upload a fresh photo to Facebook on Android?  One take with the camera of the phone.  I have Android 2.1update1.

Comment: Using the official Facebook app, a third party app, or the browser?

Comment: through the web browser it uploads it to a dir named: mobile uploads, and I can't place it elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use your browser to upload the image, try switching out of mobile view from the page footer. Then you should be able to upload it the same way as on a desktop browser. You could also use the apps (either official or third-party) for more upload options.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [official Facebook app](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.facebook.katana) you can upload a picture, either from the gallery, or live straight from the camera, it then allows you to pick an album to add the picture too.

Open the facebook app and click the camera icon in the top-left corner. you're now given a choice to either go to the camera and take a picture, or go to your gallery and select a picture to upload.

[image]

While the picture is uploading, there is a text box that allows you to enter a caption for the picture, and there is an icon in the top right corner that will show you a list of all of your icons and pick which one to upload the picture to.

[image]

Once your picture has uploaded, you can go into the Photos section of the Facebook app, go into the album you picked, open the picture, and you should now be able to read/leave comments, or change the caption.